# Simple supersaw lead

Tags: synthesizer

I am pretty sure it is something really simple to do, but I am not able to get the **exact** same thing. If possible I want to know how to do it perfectly, shouldn't be too hard :) Thanks!

It starts at 8 seconds and stops at 11 seconds:

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you here. A supersaw is a supersaw. I.e. multiple (like up to 8) saw oscillators slightly detuned (so that the sum sounds pleasing) and possibly pitched apart by some octaves. The rest is just balancing the parameters (primarily the amount of detuning in cents) until it sounds nice.

Comment: Sound Design is a site for sound design and production professionals and enthusiasts.  Music related sound design that would be done by musicians is off topic as this is not a Q/A site for musicians.  

While musicians also design sounds, it is a different style with different requirements and needs than what is covered here.  You may have better luck at [Musical Practice & Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A (Roland) supersaw is actually a term for seven simultaneous saw waves, originating from the JP-80x0 synths. On the synths the oscillators can be detuned relatively with one knob and this is the supersaw-sound we all know from trance tracks etc. and it will give you the closest result.

You can come quite close by using three oscillators tuned at 0, -12 and +12 cents (give or take a few cents) respectively. Put the 0 one at the highest volume and adjust the other two oscillator volumes to taste, to simulate the "amount of supersaw" you want. You can then duplicate this track and detune the whole second synth to layer six saw waves.

I use this technique in my trance tracks all the time. You can try adding a chorus, too, to get that extra, detuned little flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Detuned saws. They sound filtered, there's an envelope on the pitch at the attack of the sound, there might be a noise osc as well and they've been colored with some strong compression. You might want to look up a tutorial for whats sometimes called the dominator synth, its along those lines.

As long as you don't to copy that melody you should be fine... because its awful.